# Calling a Jenkins job from a Codefresh pipeline fails with: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided

Tags: ssl, jenkins, codefresh

I have a Jenkins job which I would like to invoke from my Codefresh pipeline.

Using the following example from the Codefresh docs, I have my Codefresh pipeline configured and ready:
https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/integrations/jenkins-integration/#calling-jenkins-jobs-from-codefresh-pipelines

The resulting build runs with the following output:

```
Pulling image codefresh/cf-run-jenkins-job:latest                                                                                                           
Pulled layer '1160f4abea84'                                                                                                                                 
Pulled layer '6df1582e0e0e'                                                                                                                                 
Digest: sha256:a95b23c24b51d5fc1705731f7d18c5134590b4bc61b91dcf5a878faf2aec60b3                                                                             
Status: Downloaded newer image for codefresh/cf-run-jenkins-job:latest                                                                                      
INFO[0000] Going to trigger <jenkins_job_name> job on https://<jenkins_host>:8443                                                         
ERRO[0000] Post https://<jenkins_host>:8443/job/<jenkins_job_name>/build: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided         
Successfully ran freestyle step: Triggering Jenkins Job                                                                                                     
Reading environment variable exporting file contents.                                                                                                       
Reading environment variable exporting file contents.
```

As you can see, the build fails to successfully trigger the Jenkins job.
After some research in the Internet I came to conclusion that this is an SSL certificate issue.

But I have no idea how to proceed from here on. What exactly is missing and where it should be configured. I would really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that kind of SSL configuration your Jenkins server has? Is it mutual authentication or just a server-side certificate? Is it self-signed or not?

Have you tried to call the Jenkins API on your own (outside of Codefresh) and SSL works fine?

Also I would suggest you open a support ticket (from the top right menu in the Codefresh UI) and make sure to mention the URL of the build that has this issue.

Comment: 1. The certificate on the Jenkins side is provided by Cloudflare, I don't know how it's configured there.
2. Yes, when we invoked the Jenkins API with curl (ignoring the certificate verification), it worked fine.
3. In the end we solved it by using a Bash image instead of codefresh/cf-run-jenkins-job